# How to define a view using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I got a problem while creating a view using **pgAdmin**. My interface containing the creation of the view have four tabs. The first is called **General** I write there the name of my view, the second is called **Definition** it's where I define my view, but the problem is when I write a thing here it's written in the last tab **SQL** and I can't write anything in this tab. I would like to know how to have the hand to write the SQL Query in the view.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to write your select query in Definition tab. In SQL tab you can see result of all you have made in previous tabs - it's a sql preview of your view. I suggest you read about creating views or play a while with this creator, see result in the SQL tab and create your view using query editor.

Comment: @112g ok thanks for the response  I got an other problem I would like to create a View that have the same name of a table, but I got "vw_xxx" is not a view. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You need to create it in different schema/database if you want to have the same name for table and view. Otherwise how would Postgres know from what to get data if you do `SELECT * FROM vw_xxx`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a view with the same name of the table. 
You have to open a Sql tab and write your DDL like this example:

```
CREATE VIEW nameoftheview AS
    SELECT *
    FROM nameofthetable
    WHERE field = 'value';
```